# SQL Server Data Tools 2012 Licensing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have installed SQL Server Data Tools for 2012 to have BI template available for Visual Studio Express 2012.

It installed correctly and I can create project in VS 2012 Express.

I would like to know if there is some license required or it is free to use.

Please guide.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software licensing and not about programming.

Comment: Your best bet is to contact Microsoft customer service, this is a question that has a lot of variables to it.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027) is free to use. However SQL Server is not free. Only SQL Server Express is free.

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx), that explains the difference between all the versions of SQL Server. Here is another link that explains [licensing](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx) with Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Arun, the link clearly states it is free tool and integrated to VS Express. Thanks a lot for the information, somehow I could not found that information.

Comment: They have not mentioned it can be used in VS 2012 Express but 2013.   Can you please check?

Comment: @AmitKB, yes it can be used. You can download here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843